# How can I create a bootstrapper which will install 3rd party exe followed by 2 msi apps

Tags: .net, msbuild, wix, installation

Im inexperienced with creating setup projects and was hoping for some direction regarding the best, most flexible, and easiest way of creating a setup bootstrapper. I need custom actions to check for existing versions, ability to install 3rd party application, several inhouse msi applications etc.
Currently I've considered the following options, installshield, VS setup project, msbuild, wix. But after a couple days searching still looking for the recommended approach here.
Any advice appreciated

Comment: You could write your own bootstrapper in C.

Comment: @ Nick - I'll give this a go. I was thinking of simplifying things by using dotNetInstaller

Answer (score 0):

Most of the tools you mentioned support what you want in one way or another. It really depends on what you want to use.

If you want a free solution, Wix is the best. It's not so easy to configure prerequisites with it, but it can be done:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm

If you want a commercial solution, I recommend Advanced Installer or InstallShield. You need to purchase a license, but you can configure your installer with a couple of clicks.

So you should first decide on what tool you want to use and then see if you encounter any problems.

Comment: I think longer term I'll look at Wix, but for now a bootsrapper might be the way to go